# disable arrow key on scheduler control

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

is there a way to disable arrow key right and left ? because i dont want user to see a date before `10 october` and date after `16 october`

[image]

i have try this code

```
       private void schedulerControl1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {

            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

it still can click arrow key, and i have check that `schedulercontrol` properties got no `keypreview`. or maybe set disable for user cant click or focus on cell

n.b : iam using `devexpress` with component `scheduler`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize IKeyboardHandlerService.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IKeyboardHandlerService oldKeyboardHandler = (IKeyboardHandlerService)schedulerControl1.GetService(typeof(IKeyboardHandlerService));
        if (oldKeyboardHandler != null)
        {
            MyKeyboardHandlerService newKeyboardHandler = new MyKeyboardHandlerService(schedulerControl1, oldKeyboardHandler);
            schedulerControl1.RemoveService(typeof(IKeyboardHandlerService));
            schedulerControl1.AddService(typeof(IKeyboardHandlerService), newKeyboardHandler);
        }
    }
}

public class MyKeyboardHandlerService : KeyboardHandlerServiceWrapper
{
    IServiceProvider provider;

    public MyKeyboardHandlerService(IServiceProvider provider, IKeyboardHandlerService service)
        : base(service)
    {
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    public override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(e.KeyCode == Keys.Left|| e.KeyCode == Keys.Right))
                        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer these DevExpress threads which may be similar to your requirement and the [SchedulerControl.LimitInterval Property](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraSchedulerSchedulerControl_LimitIntervaltopic) of the control:

[Restrict TimelineView to show only selected date range](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T128647)
[Scheduler: Limit days/hours displayed in Gantt-view](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q405827)
[Restricting Date Range in Schedule Control, TimeScale view](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q405827)
[Limit timeline view to specified interval (1 day?)](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q100906)
[Timeline view : how to adjust the number of visible days](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q252580)