# how to limit interval by day name in scheduler?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

i have a scheduler component from devexpress. i want to set the limit interval by day name instead of date. iam using this code

```
  schedulerControl1.ActiveViewType = evExpress.XtraScheduler.SchedulerViewType.WorkWeek;
  schedulerControl1.LimitInterval.Start = Datetime.today;
  schedulerControl1.LimitInterval.End = Datetime.today;
```

when iam trying to view it by day(tommorow or yesterday), it only preview me the today date. i know iam using limit interval wrong. how can i modified it to limit it by dayname the code i want is like this

```
  schedulerControl1.LimitInterval.Start = Day.Monday;
  schedulerControl1.LimitInterval.End = Day.Sunday;
```

it give error of `cannot implicitly convert type system.windows.form.day to system.datetime`

[image]

iam using limit, so user cant scroll before `10 october` and after '16 october`

before this thread, iam already ask but it didnt give me what i want. and iam also already tried the refer link.
[disable arrow key on scheduler control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018903/disable-arrow-key-on-scheduler-control)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below methods are  use full to get first and last date of current week as per your requirement

```
public static DateTime FirstDayOfWeek(DateTime date)
    {
        DayOfWeek fdow = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;
        int offset = fdow - date.DayOfWeek;
        DateTime fdowDate = date.AddDays(offset+1);
        return fdowDate;
    }

    public static DateTime LastDayOfWeek(DateTime date)
    {
        DateTime ldowDate = FirstDayOfWeek(date).AddDays(6);
        return ldowDate;
    }
```

then do

```
 schedulerControl1.LimitInterval.Start = FirstDayOfWeek(DateTime.Now);
  schedulerControl1.LimitInterval.End = LastDayOfWeek(DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: thanks man thats what iam looking for. first of all when i try this to implement this code it wont work what iam expected. when i debug it the firstday of week is wednesday i wonder why. but when iam see the setting format of pc the first day of week is wednesday. so when i changing it to sunday it works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this post in DX forum should help you (there is a complete code sample attached):
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q534116

Basically, the idea is that you need to *"define an empty DateHeaderTemplate and fill the Resource collection with seven resources associated with the corresponding weekdays"*. See the actual sample to see how the DX support staff did it.

Let me know if have difficulties understanding the mentioned sample.